# Can public files in Ubuntu One be found through search engines?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I know that the published files are not private but its not clear for me.

Lets take a look at the sharing service of Google Drive, you can share your files in Google Drive on 3 way:

1. private (It's not part of my question!)
2. public on the web (anyone on the Internet can find and access)
3. Anyone with the link (Anyone who has the link can access)

Now my two questions about published files in my Ubuntu One cloud are:

1. Can anyone who doesn't have the link, access my published files? (as
   long as I don't share the published link with anyone on the web)
2. Can anyone find them via search machines like Google?

Comment: As anyone can read, both question are the same. I remarked this in the title

Comment: if you can find, you can read it...that's true BUT is that mean also you can always find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has the link to a public file on Ubuntu One, then that link could be posted anywhere else on the web, and any search engine spider bot could index the sites which include the link. At this point, the link may show up in search results.

However, there is no way for the spiders to index them otherwise, unless a spider were to gain access to your account, and read the list of files and public file links for your files, as there is no list of all public file URLs anywhere.